# Layout do Stack Overflow quebrado na página de perguntas

Tags: bug, layout

Notei que o layout está quebrado nas perguntas, inclusive aqui no meta. Constatei isso no Chrome, Firefox e Opera.

Demonstração:

[image: Demonstração do erro no layout (página de perguntas recentes)]

Comment: Qual resolução? Qual página? Pode ser o titulo de uma pergunta que quebrou o layout (pois é, ironicamente a SO não é tão boa para criar layouts)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ironicamente nada, a parte de UX e UI é sofrida mesmo. Falaram em contratar um especialista, mas tudo indica que não deu certo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parece que foi resolvido, era em /questions (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) e só vi em resolução >1280

Comment: @RicardoPontual pode ser um bug de um cache rápido q só você notou, ou pode ser um extensão ou algo muito especifico que você... eu ainda suponho que foi uma pergunta que talvez tenha sido deletada nesse meio tempo que tinha o titulo muito grande e por isso quebrou o layout. Apesar de não conseguir simular aqui, outras vezes que o layout quebrou foi por coisas assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ser uma pergunta sim, cache não deve ser, pq testei em 3 navegadores diferentes e o resultado foi o mesmo, ou quem sabe aconteceu um hotfix :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual falo "cache do lado do servidor", para distribuição do "build". Coisa da SO mesmo :)

Comment: Acabou de dar problema no meu layout mas já voltou ao normal. A guia *Em destaque* havia tomado a tela inteira.